# How many different subsets of a $10$-element set are there where the subsets have less than $9$ elements?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

How many different subsets of a $10$-element set are there where the subsets have less than $9$ elements?

My approach is that we can form $2^{10}$ subsets with $10$-element set and $(2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6+2^7+2^8)$ subsets with less than $9$-element set. For example, we can form $2^0$ subsets with $0$-element set and $2^1$ subsets with $1$-element set and so on. Hence, the answer is $2^{10}-(2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6+2^7+2^8)$. Is this right?

Comment: Perhaps you are confused between $k$-element subsets of a 10-element set (counted by $\binom{10}{k}$) and all possible subsets of a $k$-element set (counted by $2^k$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $2^{10}$ subsets of a $10$-element set.

One subset has $10$ elements.

$\binom{10}{9}=\binom{10}{1}=10$ subsets have $9$ elements.

So $2^{10}-(1+10)$ subsets have less than $9$ elements.

Comment: Why did you include $1$ at the end?

Comment: Are you counting the empty set which has no elements?